# Authentication: Username (email) and password hashed together in one database field

Tags: security, authentication, hash, cryptography, salt

I am currently developping a platform with a PHP framework for our client.

The head of the client's IT department wants us to handle authentication with one database field containing email+password+salt (hashed) so there isn't a plain text email field in this table and the password is more secure (his reasoning). The user should be able to login with his email address and password. So the email address serves as the username.

The idea behind this is that the email addresses of the users are very important for the business of our client and the IT head wants to obscure the email address in the login table in case of a possible attack. (e.g. a hacker gets access to the login table)

This is of course only possbile, because the hashed email adress for the login is linked to his email address in the profile table.

Basically there are two tables which are required for this process to work. The tables are in the same database of course.
One login table with the hash combination field (email, pw, salt) and one profile table which contains among other things the email in plaintext in one field. Let's call it profile_email.

I have strongly recommended not to use this solution, because I have never before heard of this and I have already identified some possible problems with this solution.

So my questions are: Is this a safe and feasible solution? Can you think of any unforeseeable problems? Have you heard of similar solutions?

Comment: Why would you split the data over 2 tables? If a hacker gets access to the Logins table he can certainly look at the Profiles table too.

Comment: This is beyond me. I told the client exactly the same thing but couldn't get a clear explanation why the split over 2 tables would make sense.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from an entity-relationship-point-of-view ...

you have a login table that either contains a field that is a concatination of hashes or a hash of a concatination of string values ...

you have a profile table that conatins the usual profile info, including a sensitive info (email)

if those two are linked by a key, the simple hashing of that email address is useless, since the same info is available as a clear text string from the profile table

in the other case, when in the login table it is ONE hash of a concatination of email password and salt, it is no added security, since the link to the profile table reveals a part of the hashed concatination ... since you also have to store the salt, and since that also has to be linked to the login entity or be part of the login entity, an attacker knows all parts of the concatination except the password ...

i can't see why this approach is a good idea, except if you split the database login for authentication from the rest ...

let's say you have in your login table:

s=randomSalt
e=cryptoHash(email,static_system_wide_salt)
p=cryptoHash(password,s)
id=KeyForRelationToOtherEntities

now the database rights to this table are restricted, and only the authenticator_user may access it, but nothing from the rest of the database

the email address in the authentication process is hashed and hardened against rainbowtable attacks

the password too

you can index the e colum for searching during the login process

the authenticator can not access profile information or other information that can be linked to the login entity, since the access rights restrict the authenticator to the login table

the rest of the system can't access the login table for the same reason

one additional role has to be taken into account, regarding password changes and creating new users if the authenticator may only read the login table

... just my 2 cents here ... it's just an idea, and not really complete, or guaranteed to be secure ... just an idea that picks up the general idea of separating the login table

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely clear about your scenario, but i guess it's something like this:

```
valueToStore = hash(email) + delimiter + hash(password, salt) + delimiter + salt;
```

This would allow to search for the email, but only if the email is made case insensitive (e.g. lower case). Otherwise you could even get duplicates with the same e-mail address.

Because the hashed email is only part of this field, searching in the database is more difficult and slower. If the user changes his email address, you would have to update both fields, the password table and the profile_email table.

Because the email is available in another table anyway, it is incomprehensible why this should be more secure. If an attacker has read access to the database (e.g. SQL-injection), there is nothing to prevent him from query the other table too.

It would be more safe, if the email would be *encrypted* (not hashed) in the other table too. Then you can search for the email by hash and nevertheless encrypt the email with an IV.

In every case i would not store the hashed email and the password-hash into a single field. If hashed correctly then other parameters like cost factor and algorithm are also part of the password-hash, this is enough for a single field.